# Hashmap lookup returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

Why is the hashmap lookup failing?
I'm cloning Key in this code to simulate a receiving a copy the key from a second source. Both key and key2 are identical byte arrays.

From the commented out portion, it can be verified that the hash map do indeed contains the value. So why does the lookup fail?

```
public class NewClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<byte [], String> lookupTable = new HashMap<>();

        byte[] key =  new byte[32], key2;
        SecureRandom sr  = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextBytes(key);


        String value = Arrays.toString(key);         
        lookupTable.put(key, value);


        key2 = key.clone();

        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(key));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(key2));

        System.out.println("Keys equal: "+ Arrays.equals(key2, key));

        String retrivedValue;
        /*
        Set<byte[]> keySet = lookupTable.keySet();
        for(byte[] k :keySet ){
        System.out.println("key in map : "+ Arrays.toString(k));
        retrivedValue = keyLookupTable.get(k);
        System.out.println("Test lookup sucessful:"+retrivedValue.equals(value));
        }
        */
        retrivedValue = lookupTable.get(key2);
        try {
            System.out.println("Test lookup sucessful:" + retrivedValue.equals(value));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {            
            System.out.println("retrivedValue is "+retrivedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Keys equal: true
retrivedValue is null
```

Comment: You'll want to compare the hashCode and equals methods directly and see if those match. Also dig into weeds on the clone method here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Comment: When choosing names for your program artifacts such as `retrivedValue`, it's good engineering to use conventional spelling for the name parts. It reduces the chances of bugs creeping in during downstream maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` lookup isn't going to use `Arrays.equals`, but simply normal `.equals`, which will fail for the two arrays.

This is why you basically *can't* use arrays as map keys; you must wrap them in a class with a `.equals` implementation.

Comment: @Soumy, the point of this answer is that the array `equals` implementation uses identity comparison as inherited from `Object`, not value comparison. That means that even if two arrays have the same content, they're only equal if they're actually the same array. So no, the array you were searching for was not in the key set of the map. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7

Comment: My guess from the OP's post was that since they were using `Arrays.equals` in their example program, they understood what `Object.equals` did on arrays, but not how maps used them.

Comment: One workaround is to use [ByteBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap-byte:A-) as keys, since ByteBuffer does implement an equals method that compares its contents.